# make a background image adjust to devices of all screen sizes

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have an image it's serving as the background for some other elements on my website, the problem is the image is wider than it is tall. For users of computers, tablets in landscape, and other screens that are wider than they are tall, this dose not pose a problem. But for users of phones it dose create a problem the image resizes so that the entire thing fits on the screen, is there a way I have the sides of the image be cut off. I need to keep any CSS as part of the bootstrap framework, or in the style tag, I tried using overflow but it didn't make a difference.

Here is my code.

```
<div class="text-white" style="
background-image: url('/static/ghc_building_darkened.jpg');
background-position: 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 100vh;
overflow: auto;
width: auto;
background-size: 100%;
">
  code omitted here.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all CSS properties with following CSS properties:

```
background-image: url('/static/ghc_building_darkened.jpg'); 
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
height: 100vh;
width: auto;
overflow: auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the property background-size to contain or cover, according to what you want the image to do. Contain will adjust the image so that the longest dimension fits inside the container, and the cover adjusts the image, so that the shortest dimension takes full space.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).